# What does an expression like arr[''hi there"] imply?

Tags: c, arrays

If a=3 and b=5 what does this imply?

```
printf(&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"], &b["junk/super"]);
```

I know that `arr[4]` means `*(arr+4)` so I need to know what does an expression like `"hi there"` imply?

EDIT - Question in probably clearer terms:

When a string is used as an array subscript what value does it convey ?

Why is output of above `Hello! how is this? super` ?

Comment: are you asking what you would get if you use a[3] and b[2] as array positions?

Comment: I seriously hope that's just an "academic" code snippet rather than something that's actually used in production.

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by "hi there"?

Comment: It implies, flee code immediately. If this was from a professor, it implies that the professor doesn't know when to flag an example as bad. If this was from production code, it implies that you hired on in the wrong company.

Comment: Interesting. It appears someone wanted to index into a constant string, and was unwilling to assign it to a variable. At the cost of confusing anyone who came after...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That implies, the printf becomes equivalent to this:

```
printf("Hello! how is this? %s\n", "super");
```

which will print:

```
Hello! how is this? super
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/PVzUP

**Explanation:**

When we write `char s[]="nawaz;` and then `s[2]` means 3rd character in the string `s`. We can express this by writing `"nawaz"[2]` which also means 3rd character in the string `"nawaz"`. We can also write `2["nawaz"]` which also means 3rd character in the string. In your code, the `printf` uses the last form, i.e of the form of `2["nawaz"]`. Its unusual, though.

So `a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"]` means 4th character in the string (as the value of `a` is 3), and if you add `&` infront of `a` then `&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"]` returns the *address* of the 4th character in the string, that means, in the printf it becomes equivalent to this:

```
Hello! how is this? %s\n
```

And I hope you can interpret the rest yourself.

Comment: I am still perplexed over the "hi there" question though... :\

Comment: @nawaz: the OP updated b to `b = 5`, which changes your answer output.

Comment: @j.w.r: I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for informing that. :-)

Comment: @Soren: OP has change the value of `b` from `2` to `3`. Anyway, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @0A0D I don't really understand what was meant by "what does an expression like <X> imply?". I think it's supposed to be something like "how is the expression <X> interpreted in this context?". `"hi there"` is a string literal; it has type `const char[9]`. `2["hi there"]` is equivalent to `*(2 + "hi there")`; in that context, the array decays to a pointer (type `const char*`), and adding an integer to a pointer then behaves as normal.

Comment: @Karl: Well, I am glad you could translate that into what you said. Perhaps if the OP was clearer in what exactly he was getting at (btw, the title has nothing to do with the content of this question?).

Answer (score 11):

If `arr[4]` means `*(arr+4)`, then `4[arr]` means `*(4+arr)`. Since addition between pointers and integers is commutative, these are identical.

The answer could be very different if you are working in C++ with objects that have overloaded operators. In that case, your question is not sufficiently complete.

Comment: I don't think that's the question…

Comment: @Sidyll - I think that is the answer to what the question should be.

Comment: @sidyll, it's exactly the question. Replace `4` with `a` or `b` and a light bulb should click.

Comment: @Mark yes, I know, but with literals? Hmm, I don't think that makes sense. At least in C.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Yes, it works: http://ideone.com/kMbMn Impressive. And sorry for being such bonehead, it just happens that the more I work with C the less I know.

Answer (score 5):

If `a` and `b` are integers, these two lines are equivalent:

```
printf(&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"], &b["junk/super"]);
printf(&("Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"[a]), &("junk/super"[b]));
```

And this is an interesting read: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/086.htm

Comment: This is the first post that I've seen that explains the output in Nawaz's answer. Very interesting.

Comment: @sun ok, sorry then, I didn't get your question. maybe the read is still interesting though ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The type of `"hi there"` is `const char[9]`, an array of 9 characters.

Considering that, we can index into that array using `"hi there"[a]` if a is between 0 and 8.

And like you said, `x[i]` is equivalent to `*(x + i)`, `*(i + x)`, and therefore also `i[x]`. So we can write `"hi there"[a]` as `a["hi there"]` just to confuse everybody.

Answer (score 0):

> if a=3 and b=5 what does this imply
>
> printf(&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"], &b["junk/super"]);

An [] operator is in original C definition just an offset operation, which in assembler is translated as

```
   x[y] => (addr = x + y; fetch content at addr)
```

So where x is typically a pointer and y is an index from that pointer, then the asember does not really care if you switch them around.

So the code is equvalent to the more understandable version

```
   printf(&("Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"[a]), &("junk/super"[b]));
```

Or with the a=3 and b=5 eliminated out

```
   printf("Hello! how is this? %s\n", "super");
```